# Tagit with json and autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete

I am using tagit [Tagit](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/) for my wordpress site for adding tags through front-end. So far the taglist is displaying fine through json (for json I use the [json api](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)

However, I can not get the autocomplete to work. If a user starts typing on the input field it displays all the tags. But I want to filter the taglist as soon as the user starts typing (if a user types 'mijn' the results should be 'termijn' but also 'mijnserver'.)

This far I have to following in my function:

```
    $value = '';

if ( $post_id ) {
    $post_tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'post_tag' );
    $tagsarray = array();
    foreach ($post_tags as $tag) {
        $tagsarray[] = $tag->name;
    }

    $value = implode( ', ', $tagsarray );
}

?>
<div class="wpuf-label">Business Tags</div>
<div class="wpuf-fields">
    <input type="text" id="test" name="tags" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>" size="40">
```

The javascript:

```
jQuery(function($)
{
    $("#test").tagit({
    fieldName: "tags[]",
   singleField: true,
    allowSpaces: true,
    minLength: 2,
    matchContains:true,
    removeConfirmation: true,
    placeholderText: 'Kernwoord',

    tagSource: function( request, response ) {
        console.log("1");
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/sbnl/api/get_tag_index/?dev=1", 
           data: {term:request.term},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                response($.map(data.tags, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.title,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                }));
            }

        });
    },

    });
});
```

last bit of the code:

```
    </div>
<?php
```

If someone could please help me out

Comment: Is that stray comma after the `tagSource` function intentional? Does your object include more functions and/or properties not shown above?

Comment: You seem to be making ajax request to something that doesn't look like WP endpoint, what is it?

Comment: Well, I found the javascript code on the internet and used it, but if I read your comments this is not going the work...I am new in learning php and javascript :-)